# Hibernate: Find just persisted object in different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have several threads in my application - where one is waiting to be notified in some changes in the database. My problem is that once I persist some object and notify the other thread - when it queries the database for new object since last change, the persisted object is not found.

```
  @Transactional()
  public void persistMyEntity() {
      // persisting and notifying from first thread
      Entity myEntity = new Entity();
      em.persist(myEntity)
      em.flush();
      someOtherBean.notifyChange();
  }
  ...
```

The following bean should be woken:

```
  public class SomeOtherBean {

      public void notifyChange() {
          currentThread.interrupt();
      }


      public void run() {
          currentThread = Thread.currentThread();

          while(true) {
              ...
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(VERY_LONG_TIME);
              } catch (InterrupedExcdeption e) {
                  // we don't care
              }

              findNewPersistedObjects();
              // nothing is found
          }
      }
  }
```

If I restart the thread, it properly finds the new object.

EDIT: Splitting the transactional method did not make any difference:

```
  public void persistMyEntity() {
      proxy(this).persistMyEntityInternal();
      someOtherBean.notifyChange();
  }

  @Transactional
  public void persistMyEntityInternal() {
      // persisting and notifying from first thread
      Entity myEntity = new Entity();
      em.persist(myEntity)
      em.flush();
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is the transaction demarcation.

You notify your other thread before the transaction is completed. The data in a database can only be queried when the transaction creating the data is ended (with a commit) (there are some exceptions for some databases but I will not go into depth for this).

To solve your problem you have to commit your transaction before querying it from another thread.

Comment: And how do I actually commit the transaction? The `em.flush` is in a method annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: @Vojtěch the transaction is commited when the method is left. Therefore you have to query in a method after the method with the transactional annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You could register a `TransactionSynchronization` with a `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. This allows you to be called back when the trx is commited successfully.